# Checking for multiple Unique fields in MySQL prior to post using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, unique

I have the following code and it inserts a record, but I want the username and email fields to be unique how can I modify my code to do this? I am also having trouble with the page not redirecting to the site index. Any help is apreciated

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "createAccount")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tblUser (username, password, userTypeKey, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['username'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['user_password2'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['userType'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['user_email'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_ignite, $ignite);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $ignite) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "index.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 }

header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is write a SELECT statement, and query the database for the $_POST['username'] OR $_POST['user_email']  then write an IF statement to react accordingly.  IF the select finds an existing account, report an error, ELSE do your insert.

I created a quick and dirty example inside my own framework.  You won't be able to cut and paste this into your own code, but it should effectively demonstrate the principle.

```
$isUnique = $db->checkUniqueUser($_POST['username'], $_POST['user_email']);

if(!odbc_fetch_row($isUnique)){
    echo "No dupe.  Put your insert statement here.";
} else {
    echo "You have a dupe.";
}

//Below are functions that I would use in my Controller class.

public function checkUniqueGroup($user_name = NULL, $user_email=NULL)
{   

   $querytext= <<<EOD
    SELECT User, Email FROM YourTable WHERE User = '$user_name' OR Email = '$user_email'
EOD;

   return $this->query($querytext);
}

public function query($querytext)
{
    //This example is from my framework.  The $conn variable is instantiated in the constructor.
        return odbc_exec($this->conn, $querytext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Ok, so I thought of another way to do this WITHOUT unique indexes. Here are two approaches:

1) Include a NOT EXISTS sub-query in your INSERT to ensure that non-unique values do not exist at the time of the INSERT. Change your INSERT SQL to:

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tblUser (username, password, userTypeKey, email) SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE username = %s OR user_email = %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['username'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['user_password2'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['userType'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['user_email'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['username'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['user_email'], "text"));
```

You may also need to check mysql_errno() for a not found error before you die().

2) create a unique index on username and a unique index on user_email.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_tblUser_username
    ON tblUser ( username );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_tblUser_user_email
    ON tblUser ( user_email );
```

Then your insert will fail if there are duplicates. To handle the failed INSERTs, replace:

```
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $ignite) or die(mysql_error());
```

with something like:

```
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $ignite) or 1062 == mysql_errno() or die(mysql_error());
if (1062 == mysql_errno()) {
    // There is a duplicate. Do whatever you intend for duplicates
}
```

Why is a unique index needed? Why can't you rely on SELECT followed by INSERT guaranteeing uniqueness? Because of timing. It is quite possible for an INSERT to occur in one process in between the SELECT and INSERT in a different process. While the likelihood is low, it is still quite possible.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to read below and it worked

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    $query_dupUserCheck = "SELECT tblUser.userKey FROM tblUser WHERE tblUser.username = '".$_POST['username']."'";
    $sqlsearch = mysql_query($query_dupUserCheck);
    $resultcount = mysql_numrows($sqlsearch);

    $query_dupUserCheck2 = "SELECT tblUser.userKey FROM tblUser WHERE tblUser.email = '".$_POST['user_email']."'";
    $sqlsearch2 = mysql_query($query_dupUserCheck2);
    $resultcount2 = mysql_numrows($sqlsearch2);

    if ($resultcount > 0 & $resultcount2 > 0) { 
        print("That Username and Email Already Exists");
    } else {
        if ($resultcount > 0) { 
            print("That Username Already Exists");  
        } else {
            if ($resultcount2 > 0) {    
            print("That Email Already Exists");
            } else {

if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "createAccount")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tblUser (username, password, userTypeKey, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['username'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['user_password2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['userType'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['user_email'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_ignite, $ignite);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $ignite) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "index.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
header(sprintf("Location : %s", $insertGoTo));
}
}}}
```

Comment: You do realize that this cannot GUARANTEE uniqueness. The odds are slim, but it is still possible to get duplicates in an environment that allows for multiple executions of the script to occur at the same time.